# sql continuous column values from data for pivot table view

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have data in a table in this structure:

```
Region | Date       | Value

A      | 01/01/2014 |    100

A      | 01/20/2014 |     50

A      | 01/02/2014 |    200

A      | 01/05/2014 |    300

B      | 01/01/2014 |    50

B      | 02/15/2014 |    70

B      | 02/25/2014 |    50

C      | 05/02/2014 |    70
```

I am trying to create a pivot view like this using T-SQL queries:

```
Region | Jan-2014 | Feb-2014 | Mar-014 | Apr-2014 | May-2014 | -> thru desired month-year

A      |    150   |   200    |   0     |     0    |    300   |

B      |     50   |   120    |   0     |     0    |      0   |

C      |      0   |     0    |   0     |     0    |     70   |
```

Please note, multiple values in the same month for a given region needs to be aggregated
Months that have no records should still show up as columns with zero values (Ex: March and April)

I tired using pivot options, withroll up etc., -- but can't seem to get this to work
any help is much appreciated..

Thank you.

Comment: Output is not correct. It should be `Region A & Jan -> 650`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you do not have results for those months is because you are missing the dates that you are pivoting into columns.

There are a few ways that you can do this. You can hard code all of the date values in the `IN` portion of your query so the columns will appear:

```
select Region,
  isnull([Jan-2014], 0) [Jan-2014], isnull([Feb-2014], 0) [Feb-2014], 
  isnull([Mar-2014], 0) [Mar-2014], isnull([Apr-2014], 0) [Apr-2014],
  isnull([May-2014], 0) [May-2014], isnull([Jun-2014], 0) [Jun-2014], 
  isnull([Jul-2014], 0) [Jul-2014], isnull([Aug-2014], 0) [Aug-2014],
  isnull([Sep-2014], 0) [Sep-2014], isnull([Oct-2014], 0) [Oct-2014], 
  isnull([Nov-2014], 0) [Nov-2014], isnull([Dec-2014], 0) [Dec-2014]
from 
(
  select left(datename(month, t.date), 3) +'-'
            + cast(year(t.date) as char(4)) monthYear,
    t.region,
    t.value
  from yt t
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for monthYear in ([Jan-2014], [Feb-2014], [Mar-2014], [Apr-2014],
                    [May-2014], [Jun-2014], [Jul-2014], [Aug-2014],
                    [Sep-2014], [Oct-2014], [Nov-2014], [Dec-2014])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2fb21/16).

Another way to do this is to create a table of dates that you can use in your query. Once created, then you can use a `LEFT JOIN` to your table so you return all of the dates that you want to appear. You can either create a recursive query to generate this list in your PIVOT query, or populate a table with a list of dates. A recursive query will be similar to this:

```
;with dates (startDate, endDate) as 
(
  select min(date), cast('2014-12-31' as date)
  from yt
  union all
  select dateadd(m, 1, startDate), enddate
  from dates
  where month(startDate) + 1 <= month(enddate)
)
select startDate
from dates;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2fb21/17).  If you join this to your PIVOT, then the query will be:

```
select *
from 
(
  select left(datename(month, d.startdate), 3) +'-'
            + cast(year(d.startdate) as char(4)) monthYear,
    t.region,
    t.value
  from dates d
  left join yt t
    on month(d.startdate) = month(t.date)
    and year(d.startdate) = year(t.date)
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for monthYear in ([Jan-2014], [Feb-2014], [Mar-2014], [Apr-2014],
                    [May-2014], [Jun-2014], [Jul-2014], [Aug-2014],
                    [Sep-2014], [Oct-2014], [Nov-2014], [Dec-2014])
) piv
where region is not null;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86ad9/2). You could use this as a part of your PIVOT query, but you would still need to hand-code all of the dates in the `IN` clause for the PIVOT.

I am guessing that you want to use a dynamic SQL version of this query so the dates will change based on your needs.  The dynamic version will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @startdate datetime = '2014-01-01',
    @enddate datetime = '2014-12-01'

;with dates (startDate, endDate) as 
(
  select @startdate, @enddate
  from yt
  union all
  select dateadd(m, 1, startDate), enddate
  from dates
  where dateadd(m, 1, startDate) <= enddate
)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(left(datename(month, d.startdate), 3) +'-'
                                                      + cast(year(d.startdate) as char(4))) 
                    from dates d
                    -- where startdate >= '2014-01-01' and startdate <= '2014-06-01'
                    group by d.startdate
                    order by d.startdate
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,''),
    @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT ', isnull(' + QUOTENAME(left(datename(month, d.startdate), 3) +'-'
                                                      + cast(year(d.startdate) as char(4)))+', 0) as '+QUOTENAME(left(datename(month, d.startdate), 3) +'-'
                                                      + cast(year(d.startdate) as char(4)))
                    from dates d
                    -- where startdate >= '2014-01-01' and startdate <= '2014-06-01'
                    group by d.startdate
                    order by d.startdate
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
from dates

set @query = 'SELECT region, ' + @colsNull + ' from 
             (
                  select left(datename(month, t.date), 3) +''-''
                            + cast(year(t.date) as char(4)) monthYear,
                    t.region,
                    t.value
                  from yt t
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(value)
                for monthyear in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3944/10). This version uses the recursive CTE to generate the list of dates that will be used in the dynamic sql string.  Even though your table of data might not exist for the months displayed, you will still have a new column.

This gives a result:

```
| REGION | JAN-2014 | FEB-2014 | MAR-2014 | APR-2014 | MAY-2014 | JUN-2014 | JUL-2014 | AUG-2014 | SEP-2014 | OCT-2014 | NOV-2014 | DEC-2014 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      A |      650 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
|      B |       50 |      120 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
|      C |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |       70 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
```

Comment: Thank you ! You made a positive difference to my data situation. 

Also can results from two pivot queries be merged? The queries will have same columns. Appreciate your help

Comment: @user2365233 You could look at using a UNION

Comment: Hi
I was looking to create a view with the Pivot table query you suggested and cannot save the view due to the variables. Is there any other way to create a view that produces same results?

Comment: @user2365233 You cannot use dynamic sql in a view. You have to use a stored procedure

Comment: oh!
Would you share an example of how I can convert your query into a Stored Proc please?

Comment: Thank you !!

PS: love SQLFiddle - Just donated as well

Comment: I seem to have run into an issue here - After creating the SP the query worked initially; but now it returns no rows.
However if I print the query within the SP and then use the same query against SQL server then it fetches the rows. Am I missing any setting in my SP?

Comment: @user2365233 my suggestion would be to post a new question.